# Is there a .net equivalent to IMultiValueConverter

Tags: .net, .net-core

I find this interface in .net framemwork 4.8.1 but not in .net core 6 for example

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter?view=netframework-4.8.1

Or is there an equivalent for multibinding?